# MySQL does not store some special charters e.g. é ,ç

Tags: c#, mysql

We are uploading some data from excel file to MySQL db using c# code but MySQL skipping all these special characters, is there any way to avoid skipping these characters? Why MySQL skips them? And these alpha-bates are called as special characters or is there any specific word for them?

Comment: You will probably need to look into the encoding of the table. It might be set to `Latin-1`. If you are using characters which are in the extended latin alphabet you will need to change that.

Comment: You need to take a look at collations, also at the datatype itself, maybe you should use `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`?

Comment: Not only the encoding of the column might be a problem, but also one of the connection and/or the data that is sent. The first thing you need to ensure that the encoding of the text you send matches the on set for the connection and then that the column in which you want to save that text supports those chars.

Comment: To replicate this issue using direct insert query, I have created one test table with column having varchar datatype and kept other properties also same as original table e.g. CHARSET=latin1, COLLATE=latin1_general_ci And found little different behavior than original table. Actually this test table is allowing me to insert 'François' without skipping 'ç'.
Not getting what is the issue with original table.

Comment: The issue you are dealing with is character sets and encodings. As mentioned above you need to ensure the connection, the table's columns and the output are all use the correct character set and encoding to see your characters come out correctly. It's a big topic. Strings and characters aren't as simple as you once thought. If you ultimately want to support all Unicode characters and things like emojis you need utf8mb4 in MySQL. Check our this article that talks about implementing that. https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4